# Kotlin Queue.poll() returning null even though items in list

Tags: kotlin, web-crawler

I'm trying to make a web crawler that crawls web pages and then later indexes them. Here is my code for the run function which is running on multiple threads

```kotlin
val toDownload: Queue<URL> = LinkedList(listOf(startFrom))
val alreadyFailed: HashMap<URL, Boolean> = hashMapOf()
val printEvery: Int = 100

fun loop(initial: Boolean = false, threads: Int = 1) {
  var counter = 0
  // Loop until we either have required number of pages or toDownload is empty
  while (((!initial && index.size <= maximumNoOfPages) || (initial && toDownload.size <= threads)) && (toDownload.isNotEmpty() || initial)) {
    // Get the next url from the queue
    val currentUrl = toDownload.poll()
    try {
      // Make sure the url exists and hasn't already been downloaded
      if (currentUrl != null && alreadyFailed[currentUrl] == null && index[currentUrl] == null) {
        counter = 0
        val downloaded = currentUrl.download()
        // Add the downloaded contents to the index
        index[currentUrl] = downloaded
        // Add all the extracted links from the webpage to the queue, filtering duplicates
        toDownload.addAll(
          downloaded.extractLinks().distinct()
            .filter { !index.containsKey(it) && !alreadyFailed.containsKey(it) && !toDownload.contains(it) })
//        println(index.size)
        if (index.size % printEvery == 0) {
          println("${((index.size.toDouble() / maximumNoOfPages) * 100).roundToInt()}%")
        }
      } else {
        counter++
        if (counter > 100) println("INFINITE LOOP Condition1: ${currentUrl != null} Condition2: ${alreadyFailed[currentUrl] == null} Condition3: ${index[currentUrl] == null} NextDownload: ${toDownload.peek()} CurrentUrl: ${currentUrl} toDownloadNotEmpty: ${toDownload.isNotEmpty()} toDownloadSize: ${toDownload.size}")
        if (counter > 105) break
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      // Url failed to download
      // Add to failed list to not reattempt in future
      if (currentUrl != null) alreadyFailed[currentUrl] = true
    }
  }
  println("FINISHED")
}
```

This works most of the time, but especially when crawling a larger amount of web pages, I get this error that appears on all threads and causes them to go into an infinite loop. Here is the output I get from all the threads when they terminate (the size varies, sometimes it's 3000 and sometimes 70,000 so I don't believe it's a size limitation of the queues)

```
INFINITE LOOP Condition1: false Condition2: true Condition3: true NextDownload: null CurrentUrl: null toDownloadNotEmpty: true toDownloadSize: 28035
```

As you can see, both the nextDownload, and CurrentUrl are null, even though the toDownload queue isn't empty and has 30000 elements.

I've tried adding the filter function when adding all the extracted links to prevent adding duplicates but this hasn't helped. It seems to happen randomly, sometimes happening shortly after running the code, and sometimes near the end of crawling with nothing being changed.

I have also defined both the equals and hashcode classes on both URL and WebPage.

I'd be happy if anyone could shed some light on what's going on.

EDIT: It also doesn't always happen on all threads. Sometimes it only affects one thread but sometimes it affects all of them

Comment: Perhaps you inserted a `null` into `toDownload`? Try printing the first 10 elements of `toDownload`. See if they are null.

Comment: And just to be clear, when you say there are multiple threads, you don't mean that multiple threads have access to `toDownload`, right? `LinkedList` is not thread safe.

Comment: Yes I do have multiple threads accessing toDownload. Could that be the problem?

Comment: And it's not possible for there to be null values because I filter them all out in the extractLinks() function

Comment: "Yes I do have multiple threads accessing toDownload" Well yeah that's a problem. `LinkedList` is not thread safe. How about adding a lock/mutex?

Comment: Ah yes, I've changed it to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue and it seems to be pretty stable for now. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Returning null is actually a fairly mild example of a concurrency failure…  (I had a case — in production, no less! — of a race condition causing HashMap.get() to go into an infinite loop!)  If you could access any collection etc. from multiple threads, **always check for thread-safety**, and protect/wrap/replace it if needed.